# Discord Bot getting username of author of message

Tags: javascript, discord

Im tried to do

```
.setTitle(`Congratulations, ${message.author.username}`)
```

but im getting this error when i do that :

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

How can i fix it? There is a problem with intents or partials?

Comment: message is not defined, define message and try again...

Comment: I have my own discord bot. Goodluck with yours

Comment: @impeR You'd have to get a message from a message event first, which is sent asynchronously, before you can access the the message author. You also need to post more of your code if you need more help. Don't bash others that come to guide you either!!

Comment: Then you should know by now that you have to give the message parameter to your function.. as it is defined in the message event

Comment: Im sorry, how to define message?

Comment: Check my answer down below

Comment: @impeR Your post needs some more details. The code you have provided is not enough to find the issue here. This makes it confusing for others to answer your question and may result in answers with assumptions. [Edit] your question and add relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the message parameter to your function. Do it as following

```
function congrats(username, message) {
    .setTitle(`Congratulations, ${message.author.username}`)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but .setTitle is not working in function. is there another way to define message?

Comment: Add the message attribute to your initial function that does the settitle. I cant rly help alot as I basically only have one line of your code and have no further clue how the rest looks